# "set is iterable,but set is not sequence"，I have some questions

Tags: python

I am reading the book fluent python. It says all collections such as `list`, `set` are iterable. But `set` is not a sequence. Dictionary is also not a sequence, that is to say, the item in sequence can not be accessed by index, such as `set[9]`, am I right? It's a bit like both linked lists and lists can be traversed, but only arrays can quickly get values through an index. I was wondering How is dictionary traversed?

Please forgive me for my poor English

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: it means data stored in dict,set is not in sequence unlike list.also in dicts you have key value pairs. you use keys to traverse dicts

Answer (score 1):

All containers in Python can be traversed like this:

```
d = { 1: 'Blue', 2: 'Green' }
for k in d:
  print(k)
```

This will iterate over the **keys** of the dictionary, i.e. 1 and 2, and is equivalent to this:

```
for k in d.keys():
  print(k)
```

If you need only the **values**, this will do:

```
for v in d.values():
  print(v)
```

And if you need **both** key and value at the same time, use this:

```
for k, v in d.items():
  print(k, v)
```

One major difference between sequences and unordered containers such as set or dict is that during traversal, there is no guaranteed order.

See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict for more details on the dict API.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question can be found in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques), as mentioned in the comments. The answer is

```py
d = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}

# Way 1
for key in d:
    print(key, d[key])

# Way 2
for key, value in d.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Different structures in python

- **Sets** are Unordered collection of unique objects. They can be iterated but not indexed like how you do on **lists** or **arrays**.
- **Dictionary** is similar to hash or maps in other languages. It is unordered and consists of key value pairs. The value can be accessed by unique key
  in the dictionary. Unlike sets, it can be iterated as well as indexed
  through one of its keys.
- **List** are just like arrays or vectors in C++. They can be iterated and indexed by numbers from 0 to length-1.

So , coming to your question, a dictionary can be traversed using its keys, it's values or the key-value pair. Below are the 3 ways to traverse a dictionary :

```
for key in dict : 
    print(key)


for value in dict.values() :
    print(value)

for key,value in dict.items() :
    print(key,value)
```

Hope this helps !